# Android Social network login

Tags: android, social-networking

I am new in android.Now i am creating social network login part in my application.Is any one give me one example for login into app using socialnetworks.In that one usernot need to enter his username  and password if he is already sign in the social network using another application.Please help me

Comment: You might want to read about shared preferences.

Comment: How my app detect the user is already login in the social network using another app

Comment: do you want to add facebook,google+ or any social network login to your app,right?

Comment: yes.I want to add facebook,google+ or any social network login to app

Comment: check this example to add googl+ login:  http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Answer (score 1):

- For Facebook login you need:

  1. Facebook SDK
  2. Facebook App ID
  3. Android Key Hash

Check this link for more details:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.2

- For Google+ login you need:

  1. Google Play Services API
  2. You need to enable the Google Plus API on google console
  3. And you need to register your digitally signed .apk file’s public certificate (SHA-1 fingerprint) in the Google APIs Console.

Check this example for more details: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/